# jQuery 2.1.3 and IE11 selector issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have an HTML input element as follows:

```
    <input class="theClass" type="text" size="20" placeholder="Search..." value="">
```

and I select it with:

```
    $('.theClass').val();
```

It works as expected in every browser except for Internet Explorer, which returns only an empty string regardless of the input. Any ideas why this might be? I am unable to find any information about compatibility issues directly related to this issue.

Comment: [**Works fine.**](https://jsfiddle.net/53w4ozo3/) You have an issue in your code elsewhere. Check your console log for errors.

Comment: on windows 10, IE11 and jQuery 2.1.3 there is no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem there...

Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        alert($('.theClass').val());
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<input class="theClass" type="text" size="20" placeholder="Search..." value=""><br />
<button>Click</button>
```